# Keep folder names the same on all places

Tags: terminal, finder, internationalization

I localized my Mac to Brazilian Portuguese so the folder names appear as "Imagens", "Documentos" in Finder, but on the terminal the English names are kept: "Documents", "Pictures". To avoid the confusions that I've been having, is there a way to keep the language of the system but keep the folder names consistent on all places? I don't care if they are in Portuguese or English, I just want to keep the same name in Finder, in the shell, etc.

To be more specific, I don't want to change the system language to English, I want to keep it as Portuguese, but I want Finder to show the real folder names (in English) and not the translations.

Answer (score 1):

Localization only impacts how Finder shows the names, it doesn‘t change the names itself. So you can

- switch the system back to English
- create symlinks for the portuguese names in Terminal.

Comment: I mentioned that I don't want to change the localization to English, as I prefer in Portuguese. So is there a way to change only the way Finder localizes its names?

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for clarifying this in the question. Most likely the localized names are defined in a file which is part of macOS and can't be modified.

Comment: You *could* create Finder aliases with for instance a . at the end (-> `Imagens.`) and then run `chflags hidden ~/Pictures` in Terminal to hide the localized version in Finder. Not sure this looks better though.